# Can Boost asio post "overflow" the queue

Tags: c++, boost-asio

In the event that there are too many operations to be handled and there are not enough resources (threads) to complete these operations, what happens then when you call .post?

Is there a way to drop all future operations based on the current queue size?

Comment: Yes. Best places to do such checks in function or lambda that you pass to post. How to handle too heavy load is up to you and to nature of your software, there are no silver bullet solutions.

Comment: @ÖöTiib enlighten me, how do you check the "depth" (size) of the IO queue in Asio? That would be totally worth an answer by the way

Comment: @ÖöTiib How would you check the size? I suppose I can have my own shared queue, when I post, I increment, and when I run, I decrements. but still, i have no way of knowing what the constraint is at the system level.

Comment: @sehe there are no such functions to my knowledge. I increase myself some sort of count when posting and decrease it when task is completed to monitor load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No.

No: The queue will grow indefinitely. It's like `std::vector` and co an infinite queue. There is no return value that tells you that the queue is full, neither there is blocking behavior.

Yes: The queue is only theoretically unlimited, at some point of time your machine is out of memory. At that point the the program might crash due to a bad allocation, or your OS will kill it due to extensive memory usage.